# Using JavaScript to solve a series of equations

Tags: javascript, physics

For fun, I'm trying to design a website that will help accurately measure the height of a cliff or tall structure by utilizing the current temperature and time for the object to hit the ground. I will be breaking up my question into different sections as I explain the problem.

**Physics**: The time the user records for the object to strike the ground is both the time it takes for the object to strike the ground and the time it takes for the sound to be heard by the user. For this reason, we need to record the outside temperature to correct the speed of sound through [This Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5nff.jpg). Besides this, it is some relatively simple physics of rearranging kinematic equations and logic to solve the rest.

**The Problem**: I have some experience in python, html and css but little to none in javascript. From my research, I will have to incorporate javascript to complete the calculations which is the most challenging part of this project and the section I have the least experience with. Math aside, I have simplified the problem into 5 main calculations the javascript will need to "complete" in the following order:

1) Calculate 'Vsound" temperature corrected using the equation in the "Physics" section

2) Solve [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YteM8.jpg), using the previously found 'Vsound' above. This 'A' value is the 'A' term in the quadratic formula.

3) Make all inputted time values negative.

4) Solve the [quadratic equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZMHJ.png) but only the positive root of that function. Negative is not required. The "A" value of this equation will be the solved value from step (2). The "B" value will always be 1. The "C" value will be the solved value from step (3).

5) Take the solution from step (4) and plug it into [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AuU7.jpg) to solve for the height of the cliff.

Simple!

I don't think I will have any problems with completing the html or the css components, it is more the 'script' section that I have little to no knowledge on how to complete.

Any help with how to complete any of these sections would be awesome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll want to research event listeners, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp. Functions, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp. And updating the value of an input, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp. That should at least get you started with writing something simple that you can then ask specific questions on.

Comment: I think it would be best if you supplied an example in a language you are experienced with (as explained: python). Otherwise this question is open to opinion more than it is useful

Answer (score -1):

I made this small html witch makes use of the formulas to calculate the time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var D = document;

    function calcVsound(){
        //get the inputted value
        var temp = D.getElementById('tempInput').value;
        //make it numeric
        var numericTemp = parseFloat(temp);
        //calculate sound velocity
        return getVsound(numericTemp);
    }

    function getVsound(temp){
        //The constant value
        var sp = 331;
        //The division inside the root
        var div = temp/273;
        //The square root
        var Droot = Math.sqrt(1+div);
        //The result
        return sp*Droot;
    }

    function gettingAvalue(){
        //calculating the value of "A" Step "2"
        var Vsound = calcVsound();
        var A = 9.81/(2*Vsound);
        return A;
    }

    function getInputTime(){
        //get Time from the input
        var time = D.getElementById('timeInput').value;
        //make it numeric
        var numericTime = parseFloat(time);
        //see if it is negative
        if(numericTime<0){
            //return if negative
            return numericTime;
        }else{
            //return negative value of time
            return (numericTime*(-1));  
        }
    }

    function solveQuadratic(){
        //The value of -b
        var B = -1;
        //The value of c
        var C = getInputTime();
        //The value of a
        var A = gettingAvalue();
        //Calculating b^2
        var Epow = Math.pow(B,2);
        //Calculating b^2 - 4ac 
        var InsideRoot = Epow - (4*A*C);
        //Calculating squareroot of b^2 - 4ac
        var Eroot = Math.sqrt(InsideRoot);
        //Getting the two roots
        var x_1 = (B+Eroot)/(2*A);
        var x_2 = (B-Eroot)/(2*A);
        //Getting the positive one
        if(x_2>x_1){
            return x_2;
        }else{
            return x_1;
        }
    }

    function getHeight(){
        //Solve the cuadratic formula
        var quad = solveQuadratic();
        var quad_pow = Math.pow(quad,2);
        //use the formula to calculate height
        var solution = (9.28*quad_pow)/2;
        //Show it on screen
        D.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = solution;
    }

</script>
<div>
    <span>Temperature:</span>
    <input type="number" name="Temperature" id="tempInput">
</div>
<div>
    <span>Time:</span>
    <input type="number" name="Time" id="timeInput">
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="getHeight()">
        CALCULATE
    </button>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="solution">

    </p>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps a lot! I will most likely be back to ask specifics on how you accomplished certain sections as well as why there is slight inaccuracy in the values.

Comment: Not sure giving all the code like this is really helping, even more since you did not explain the code nor how you went from the formulated problem to the code.

Comment: Well, he gave the formulas so I just read two inputs (time and temperature) and used them with the information he provided of which values he needed. I too think it´s not perfect and still could improve.